# Check duplicates of numbers input by user

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing a program where user input five numbers and in the end the numbers are printed out which is working fine. What I can't get to work is a boolean function to check for duplicates. It should check for duplicates as the user write them in, so e.g. if number one is 5 and the second numbers is also 5, you should get an error until you write in a different number. Meaning if the user input a duplicate it should NOT be saved in the array. This is obviously an assignment, so I'm just asking for a hint or two.

This program is written based on pseudo-code given to me, and therefore I have to use a boolean to check for duplicates with the `public boolean duplicate( int number )` class.

I've tried getting my head around it and tried something by myself, but obviously I'm doing a stupid mistake. E.g.:

```
if(int i != myNumbers[i]) 
   checkDuplicates = false
     else
       checkDuplicates = true;

return checkDuplicates;
```

DuplicatesTest class:

```
public class DuplicatesTest {

    public final static int AMOUNT = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Duplicates d = new Duplicates(AMOUNT);
        d.inputNumber();
        d.duplicate(AMOUNT);
        d.printInputNumbers();
    }
}
```

Duplicates class:

```
public class Duplicates {

  private int amount;    
  private int[] myNumbers; 
  private boolean checkDuplicates;

  public Duplicates(int a) {

    amount = a;
    myNumbers = new int[amount];   
}

  public void inputNumber() {

    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++ ) {
      int input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input 5 numbers"));
      myNumbers[i] = input;
    }   
}

  public boolean duplicate( int number ) {

    <BOOLEAN TO CHECK FOR DUPLICATES, RETURN FALSE OR TRUE>

  }

  public void printInputNumbers() {

    JTextArea output = new JTextArea();
    output.setText("Your numbers are:" + "\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < myNumbers.length; i++) {
      if (i % 5 == 0) {
        output.append("\n");
      }
      output.append(myNumbers[i] + "\t");
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "Numbers", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);   
  } 
}
```

Sorry if the code tag is messy, I had some trouble with white fields in between and such. I'm new here.

Comment: Just store it in an array and run through the array to check for duplicates... I don't see what the problem could be.

Comment: Paste the code of the algorithm you tried to check duplicates. The code you gave in your question isn't valid Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store the numbers in an *array*. Use a `Set<Integer>` instead. And then do a `Set#contains()` operation. It's `O(1)` operation which is actually far better than iterating over the array to search for duplicates.

Ok, if it's a compulsion to use an array, then you should modify your current approach, to return `true` as soon as you find a duplicate, instead of iterating over the array again. In your current approach, since you are setting the `boolean` variable to `false` in the `else` block, your method will return `false` if the last element of the array is not the same as what you are checking. So, just modify your approach to:

```
// loop over the array
    if (number == myNumbers[i])   
        return true;
// outside the loop, if you reach, return false
return false;
```

Note that your current `if` statement will not compile. You are declaring an `int` variable there, which you can't do.

```
if (int i == myNumbers[i])   // this is not a valid Java code.
```

Comment: I have to store it in an array, it's a part of the pseudo-code given to me.

Comment: Or even `if (Set.add(newNumber) != null) { /* Duplicate */ }`

Comment: @KlasLindbäck. That won't compile. `Set#add()` returns a `boolean`.

Comment: @Rohit Sorry, was thinking on the Map interface. I meant `if (Set.add(newNumber) == false) { /* Duplicate */ }`

Answer (score 0):

```
int nums[] = new int[5];
int count = 0;

public boolean duplicate(int number) 
{
    boolean isDup = false;

    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
    {
        if (number == nums[i])
        {
            isDup = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isDup) 
    {
        count++;
        nums[count] = number;
    } 
    return isDup;
}
```

Comment: where is `inputNum` defined? Is that `number` ?